# Visual and high CPU Utilization, is this heavy?

Tags: wpf, cpu-usage

I have a WPF Canvas with about 240 paths.  A path may go out to column 550 when I look at it in Visual Studio. It's a picture of a handheld remote with many buttons that was originally exported from adobe illustrator.

On a dual core machine, 4gb, when I show the graphic, it can spike the processor from a normal of about 10% up to 30% to 40% and it will stay there.  There's nothing going on, just sitting there. Probably nothing special with respect to the graphic card.  If I hide the graphic, the CPU usage will drop back down.

On a better machine with more cores (I7) and a better graphics card, the change is not really noticeable, but still a spike none the less.

Anyone share a similar experience?

Comment: WPF does use more processor power and memory than WinForms. Just avoid excessive animation and effects such as shadow/blur, unless you have a really powerful video card.

Comment: @m-y What if he has a really powerful video card, but his customer does not?

Comment: as a fyi... it is a situation where customers will be affected.

Answer (score 1):

WPF need powerful processor to work smoothly. But in case of lower h/w it gives lower performance, specially when animation is used.

- Reduce the frame rate of animation
- Do not use transparency unless it is required
- Use dispatcher to smooth the UI